# Починут с миром - верно?

Tags: окончания

ларьки починут с миром - предложение

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **ларьки почиют с миром.**

Пример: И да **почиют с миром** корпоративные разглагольствования о постоянном улучшении качества производимого продукта.

**Из словарей:**

**ПОЧИТЬ**, -чию, -чиешь; почивший; св. 1. Почтит. Уснуть. Спит? - Так точно, изволили п. 2. Высок. Умереть. П. на руках у кого-л. Почившая императрица, супруга. П. навеки, вечным сном. П. в боге, в мире. <**Почивать** (см.).

У Зализняка: **почить, почию, почиют**. В сем храме **почиют** останки князей русских и святителей. [Ф. В. Булгарин. Димитрий Самозванец (1830)]

**Но у Даля**: почивать, почить, **южн. зап. починуть**, спать, предаться сну, отойти ко сну; отдыхать, праздновать от трудов; покоиться, пребывать в покое, в косности, бездействии.

**Починут с миром** ― это диалектная форма от "починуть".

Comment: *Починут с миром ― это диалектная форма от "починуть".* - Ась?

Comment: Сказано ведь выше: "у Даля: почивать, почить, южн. зап. починуть"

Answer (score 2):

Нет, правильно (если буд. время; сов. вид) "*почИют в мире*":

> Почиет в мире Теодорих
>   И Дант не встанет с ложа сна.
>   (А. Блок, 1909)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд (и взгляд [Викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)), правильно - "почиют". Притом в [Мультитране](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=118&t=10164_2_1) указано, что в будущем времени "ларьки почат". Что, по всей вероятности, ошибочно.

Comment: Врет Ваш мультитран, если он и правда так считает. "Почат" - это от глагола "почать" (=начать). тhttp://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: Мультитран, скажем так, не мой вовсе) а с неправильностью "ларьки почат" я и не спорю, извините, если с толку сбивает. Только для примера источник привела.